# React-native - Change button icon when processing and should get back to its normal state after the processing is done

Tags: android, cross-platform, react-native, react-native-ios

How can I change a Button Icon while it is processing then have it go back to the default button icon after the processing is done in React-native.

For example: I have a microphone icon button and when I click on it the icon should change to show that it is processing and when recording is done then it should turn back to default microphone icon.

Comment: do you want animation?

Comment: yesssss  i want animation

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean variable and manage the ions as per that boolean.